# image swap technique - to fade instead

Tags: jquery

I am using this code below to swap on image on hover:

```
$(function() {
    $("#compost").hover(function() {
        origImage=$(this).attr("src");
        $(this).attr("src", "images/order-compost-over.gif")
    },function() {
        $(this).attr("src", origImage)
    });
});
```

Ia m trying to use fadeIn instead of a swap. I tried working it in but no luck.I tried having the img tag fadeIn but it didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [ImageSwitch](http://www.hieu.co.uk/blog/index.php/imageswitch/). Does everything you want and a fair bit more.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to "merge" the two images, you won't be able with standard techniques.

Instead, you should:

- Create a new IMG object
- Position that absolutely over the previous image
- Set the new image's src to the old one and set its opacity to 1.
- Set the old image's src to the new URL and set its opacity to 0.
- Now animate both simultaneously to oposite values
- Finally, get rid of the new image.

This is a tricky one, but should work fine :)